# Tomcat is returning XML Error when application makes an outbound Rest API request

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, tomcat, tomcat9

I have a Spring Boot application running inside Tomcat 9. I encounter an issue when I try to make an outbound HTTP request from another service. It seems like something is wrong with my Tomcat server configuration but I could not pin point to the root cause.

When I try to make a curl request directly from the server, I get the expected response. However, when I make the request through my application, I get a weird XML error and the request does not even get to the service. It is blocked from going out.

I made a few changes on my server.xml configuration. I enabled the 8443 port to enable the Http11NioProtocol and restart the server. After then I was able to make the API request to the external service. I have no idea why that worked. But it does not behave consistently. It works for some time and then it fails and return the same XML error. I then have to restart my tomcat service to make it work again.

Here is my server.xml config which is mostly default:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>


  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               />
    
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true"
               maxParameterCount="1000"
               >
        <!-- <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="conf/localhost-rsa.jks"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig> -->
    </Connector>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

This is the XML error I get:

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
       <env:Body>
        <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Internal Error</faultstring>
        </env:Fault>
      </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```